# How to associate differentes view states with differents drawable items in runtimes

Tags: java, android

how to put two drawable item, one associate to click view other state not clicked!!
  in code java !! because in my program , I create dynamically new views, whose which one of them have a different color in default state (when android:state_pressed="false").

exactly like this: but in java code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- PRESSED -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <stroke android:color="#286DCC" android:width="2dp"/>
           <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

                <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
           <gradient  android:startColor="#f1f1f2" android:centerColor="#e7e7e8" 
                      android:endColor="#cfcfcf" android:angle="270" />
     </shape>
 </item>

        <!-- DEFAULT -->
<item >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
           <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" 
                   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"  android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
                <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
           <gradient  **android:startColor="#F75522" android:centerColor="#F75522"**
                    **android:endColor="#F75522"** android:angle="270" />
     </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

I tried to modifie it like that:

```
Drawable shape = getResources(). getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_defaults);
```

by I don't know how to attain `android:startColor`,`centerColor`,`endColor` to change it dynamically.

thinks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Set onClickListener to the button and in onClick change the background of the button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if(v == ButtonName) {
     ButtonName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ImageName);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have two color of state item, the first one appears like a effect only as at the click view, the second is the default color, it appears before and after the click on view, but not when clicking.